# Destructuring useContext data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Below example works but how do I do to destructure the useContext data so that, I dont have to map in every div for every array value. I think is not clean at all. Doing it with props I know, I can map while creating the child2 component but I've tried couple ideas with useContext but not luck. Thanks in advance.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UserDataProvider>
        <Child1 />
      </UserDataProvider>
    </div>
  );
}    

export default function child1() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Child2 />
        </div>
    )
}
    

export default function Child2() {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useContext(UserDataContext)

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                {userData.map((val, index) => {
                    return (
                        <h1 key={val.id}>{val.name}</h1>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

            <div>diplay phoneNumber</div>

            <div>diplay cardNumber</div>
        </div>
    )
}   


export const UserDataContext = createContext();

const UserDataProvider = (props) => {
    const [userData, setUserData] = useState([{
        id: '1',
        name: 'PersonName',
        phoneNumber: '555555',
        cardNumber: '1234'
    }])

    return (
        <UserDataContext.Provider value={[userData, setUserData]}>
            {props.children}
        </UserDataContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default UserDataProvider
```

Comment: I guess you could return each individual value and pass them as the values provided to the context provider but it's my assumption your userData will be larger than that. I don't really see anything wrong with mapping through your context as needed for each specific value.  You could also convert it to an object

Comment: Is `userData` always an array with just one entry?

Comment: userData is just the way I found to return it so, when I need to update the data the setUserData is there to do so.

Answer (score 1):

One option I see if you're trying to prevent using an exclusive component is to use `useMemo` for your resulting rendered array. You could add this to the `UserDataProvider`:

```
const userElements = React.useMemo(() => {
  return userData
    ? userData.map(val => (<h1 key={val.id}>{val.name}</h1>))
    : []
}, [userData])
```

Then add `userElements` to the returned value properties in the context provider. I would suggest using an object for context value and not returning any variables you don't need to expose (such as userData and setUserData, at least for the example given):

```
<UserDataContext.Provider {...props} value={{userElements}}/>
```

The `userElements` would be passed into your component the same as exposing any property, i.e. `<>{userElements}</>`

Note that the way I'm using "useMemo" is just a way to skirt around writing a functional React component even though it is essentially doing the same thing. The main difference is you must specify the useMemo dependencies as the second argument explicitly to prevent unnecessary rerendering whereas a simple React component handles this natively given the supplied props (also assuming you don't add any unnecessary props to said component to cause it to rerender more than necessary).